# Restrict user to registering only once a day java

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I don't have any code so far, but my initial idea is quite simple. I will have a `JTable` with user's names, IDs, and a checkbox to indicate the user was present.

The program writes this to file by storing the `JTable` data to an array and then reading the previous file data and adding the new array data from `JTable` to it, for example:

the Array would be an object array, with each object consisting of `UserID`, `UserName`, `Present`(boolean). The text file is of format `UserID`, `UserName`, `daysPresent`, `totalDays` per each line. And so the system simply adds one to `daysPresent` if the array indicates the person was present.

My only problem is; the user can do this as many times a day as they want. The user can keep pressing submit and adding 1 to the total days present as well as the total days (submit button adds one to total days). Can anyone think of some way to restrict the user to only be able to submit a register once a day, although I am thinking of adding a checkbox for late so maybe some way in which somehow, the data for one day is only added to the array at the end of the day or something? I don't really know about that, I can't think of how I could possibly implement it. Also, how the total days is only increased if a register is completed for a certain day?

I appreciate I haven't submitted any code and there's a lot of questions but I am unable to currently start it. Apologies.

Any help is appreciated and ask any questions if you don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for each new row system date flag will suffice. So on next submit all you have to check the last row submit date.

Comment: You need to know the last time the submitted a request, or you need to associate a date with a single row, so each day can only have a single record

Comment: @User22 Then you have bigger problems.  Basically it comes down to this.  Each entry MUST have a date associated with it.  If an entry already exists for the current date, then no new entries can be added (for that user).  You don't really need `totalDays`, this can be calculated by iterating over the data and simply summing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is, you need to associate a date value with each entry

`date | userID | userName | present`

The `date` and `userID` form a unique key/relationship, meaning that only one combination of both can be allowed to exist

`daysPresent` and `totalDays` are both calculable fields, so they don't really need to be present, simply iterate of the data and sum them if you need them.

When adding data to the data source, check to see if a `date`/`userID` for the current date exists, if it doesn't reject the update, others add the new entry.

Because you're using a text file, you're going to need to manage a lot of this yourself, a database would otherwise take care of it for you

Comment: Thanks. Great implementation and idea, I'm guessing it's already an established method which is quite simple but I'm still learning and so obviously I find it very useful (also the reason I'm using text file, still a student and haven't learnt yet). Anyway, thanks a lot for your contribution. I just don't understand what you mean about not needing the 2 fields and that I can just iterate? Could you explain please?